# Expected singleton: res.users() when create new invoice programmatically

Tags: invoice, odoo-15

I'm trying to create a new invoice in controller:

```
request.env['account.move'].sudo().create([
    {
        'move_type': 'out_invoice',
        'journal_id': 1,
        'invoice_date': '2020-01-10',
        'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {'product_id': 21, 'price_unit': 1000.0})],
    }])
```

But i got this error

> Expected singleton: res.users()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer with the help of my leader, here it is:

This issue is because we missing `self.env.user`, to do this, we must add `.with_user(SUPERUSER_ID)` after model call.

Example:

```
from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID

request.env['account.move'].with_user(SUPERUSER_ID).sudo().create([
    {
        'move_type': 'out_invoice',
        'journal_id': 1,
        'invoice_date': '2020-01-10',
        'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {'product_id': 21, 'price_unit': 1000.0})],
    }])
```